# rails deleted migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I stupidly went ahead and manually deleted a migration file after having already migrated my database. 
Of course this brings an issue when I try to migrate my database again.

Is there anyway to recover from this? Sadly, I didn't add the migration to my git repository. I know what was in the migration, so maybe I could create it again, only I wouldn't know how to recover the timestamp.

Comment: Try to check your `db/schema.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `schema_migrations` table, it contains all timestamps.

Comment: Could you help me locate this schema_migrations table please?

Comment: What database are you using? `select * from schema_migrations` from console.

Comment: I'm using sqlite, this command gives me `SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('`

Comment: better use `rails dbconsole` or actual db console

Comment: Okay cool, so I just changed the timestamp and now migrating works again. Do you think there could be any possible complications?

Comment: The only one: you don't restored your table structure exactly. Did you checked it with `schema.rb`?

Comment: Yes, the name of the migration might be different (exept for the timestamp) but the contents where the same. Thanks a lot dimakura